# Minimal vertex cover of a subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph. A subset $C \subseteq V(G)$ is a vertex cover  of
$G$ if for each $e \in E(G)$, $e\cap C \neq \phi$.  If $C$ is minimal
with respect to inclusion, then $C$ is called minimal vertex
cover of $G$.

Let $G$ be a finite simple undirected graph and $H$ be a subgraph of $G$ (not necessarily induced). Assume that $H$ contains at least one edge. Let $\mathfrak A$ be a minimal vertex cover of $G$. Is the following statement true?

$\exists$ $\mathfrak B\subseteq\mathfrak A$, $\mathfrak B\neq\emptyset$ such that $\mathfrak B$ is a minimal vertex cover of $H$.

---

My guess is that it is true. Argument:

Since $H$ can be obtained from $G$ by deleting some edges, $\exists$ some $\mathfrak B'\subseteq\mathfrak A$ such that $\mathfrak B'$ is a vertex cover of $H$ (since $V(H)\subseteq V(G)$). Since $\mathfrak B'$ is a vertex cover of $H$, $\exists$ $\mathfrak B\subseteq\mathfrak B'$ such that $\mathfrak B$ is a minimal vertex cover of $H$.

Is the above argument correct?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I think your argument is correct. More precisely, we can take $\mathfrak{B}' = V(H) \cap \mathfrak{A}$ which is a vertex cover of $H$. Does it hold for 'minimum' vertex cover?

Comment: Oh, it does not hold for minimum vertex cover. For instance, take $G$ as adding an edge to a triangle. Denote $a,b,c$ are vertices of triangle, and $cd$ is an added edge. Then $\{a,c\}$ is the minimum vertex cover. Let $H$ be a subgraph with $V(H) = \{a,b,c\}$ and $E(H) = \{ab, bc\}$. Of course the unique minimum vertex cover of $H$ is $\{b\}$.

Comment: Dear @Dong-gyuKim My question is about minimal vertex cover. Here $\{a,c\}$ is a minimal vertex cover of $H$. There can be many minimal vertex cover of a graph.